# IAM policy document multiple key condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I have a API key and I only want to **allow** the developers to view the API key value if API key has **any one** of the following Tag(key-value pair)

```
# allow access if API key has any one of Tag with corresponding values
app: demo
OR
default:true
```

This is current IAM policy statement.

```yaml
- Effect: Allow
  Action: apigateway:GET
  Resource: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/apikeys/*
  Condition:
    StringEquals:
      aws:ResourceTag/app:
        - "${aws:PrincipalTag/app}"
      aws:ResourceTag/default:
        - "true"
```

But based on the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html#reference_policies_multiple-conditions-eval), evaluation logic is `key1:value1 AND key2:value2` which means `allow` access only if API keys has both tags with corresponding values but I need `key1:value1 OR key2:value2`. Can you please how to write the condition operator for this using single statement?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ForAnyValue:StringEquals:` condition key:

```yaml
- Effect: Allow
  Action: apigateway:GET
  Resource: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/apikeys/*
  Condition:
    ForAnyValue:StringEquals:
      aws:ResourceTag/app:
        - "${aws:PrincipalTag/app}"
      aws:ResourceTag/default:
        - "true"
```